# how to find the diameter of an object in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do you find the the diameter of a selected object in illustrator ? as in how many pixel are in the selected object ?

Comment: Are you measuring area or distance. Illustrator does not operate on pixels so its also hard to say what the resultant pixel dimension would be.

Comment: say if i was try to find the area of the object ?

Comment: the Diameter of a Circle is actually the Width or Height, to find the Area you'll need a script

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure an object in your Illustrator document in pixels, go to File > Document Setup and change units to Pixels.

Then, go to View > Show Rulers  and make sure it's turned on to show the rulers along the upper and left sides of your document window.

You can also use the Measure tool. This is on the tools palette under the eyedropper, hold down the eyedropper button and you get an option to switch tools. Draw a line across the object you want to measure, and it will show you how long it is.

Keep in mind that vectors are designed to scale smoothly and aren't locked to pixel dimensions like a photo would be. If you want to use different units to measure, just change the units in Document Setup.